# Why does far call point to a tword instead of qword in x64?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, disassembly

In NASM, `call far [edi]` gets converted to `67 48 FF 1F` which is translated as `call far tword ptr ds:[edi]` by my debugger. Why is the destination of size tword?

Comment: Because there's a 2-byte segment selector as well as the 8-byte absolute address.  Far call sets a new CS:RIP, not just RIP.  Are you sure you want a far, not just near indirect?  Also, are you sure you want to be using a 32-bit register to hold the pointer to that memory operand?